# ifelse function in r not giving proper output

Tags: r, if-statement

Trying to divide a age variable into small groups wit this function.

```
ifelse(mydata$age <= 25, mydata$age <- "youth", 
       ifelse(mydata$age <= 35, mydata$age <- "earlyjob",
              ifelse(mydata$age <= 55, mydata$age <- "mid-age",
                     ifelse(mydata$age <= 70, mydata$age <- "latejob", mydata$age <- "senior"))))
```

But it is only giving "youth" and "senior" as output.. what should I do?

Comment: You can use `cut` instead of the nested `ifelse`

Comment: and you should study the documentation. ifelse is not the same as if and else.